# Order posts by meta value and Date

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query, recent-posts

I'm trying to sort posts based on one post meta value and date. I'm using this plugin ( https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System ) to add like system to my posts.

The code that I've is as follows.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 15,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'meta_key' => '_post_like_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

The plugin adds a meta key `_post_like_count` to the table if at least one person like the post. The above code just returns posts which have at least one like count ( say 3 out of 15 ).

How do I get the remaining posts which don't have the meta key and sort them based on the date?

Answer (score 2):

If you want both posts that have and do not have a meta key, you need an `OR` relation meta query to select both posts with key and those where it does not exist.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_post_like_count',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_post_like_count',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$recent = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: This seems to be working partially. Now I'm getting all the posts, but ordering is a little messed up. The posts with 2 likes on Dec 5 comes first and then few posts published between Nov 7 and Dec 5 which have no likes at all and then posts before Nov 7 which have one like each.

Basically I want to list posts in order of max number of likes first(a) and then based on date if the posts don't have any likes after (a)

Comment: @ArjunSKumar I can't reproduce that issue, ordering works correctly when I test locally. `var_dump( $recent )` after the query is run and look at `$recent->request` to inspect the SQL query. Note that you have to be using `WP_Query` to do this, not `wp_get_recent_posts`.

Comment: I think the issue is when there are equal number of likes for a few posts. They are coming in the end and sorted based on the dates, and yes, I'm using WP_Query itself

Comment: @ArjunSKumar again, I can't reproduce that issue. Have you inspected the request and query vars and made sure no other code is altering it?

Comment: Here's the request query : `SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = '_post_like_count' ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_post_like_count' 
  OR 
  mt1.post_id IS NULL
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC "`